# Does a pressing “Ctrl+A” in a folder select the hidden items as well?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management, selection, nautilus, lxde

Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in a folder select the hidden items as well? Will copying a folder containing hidden files also copy the hidden files?

This question pertain to:

- Windows Explorer (Windows 7)
- Nautilus (Ubuntu)
- pcmanfm (LXDE)

Answer (score 9):

In Windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will not select hidden files if they are not displayed and therefore they will not be copied.

If you copy a whole folder "from the outside" which contains hidden files, the hidden files will also be copied.

Comment: Now that it's been mentioned, I'm really curious what the logic is behind this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

No, unless the hidden files display setting is enabled.

**Here's how to display hidden files and folders:**

- Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking *Appearance and Personalization*, and then clicking *Folder Options*.
- Click the *View* tab.
- Under Advanced settings, click *Show hidden files, folders, and drives*, and then click OK.

Answer (score 1):

No. As others said, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects only *visible* content so any hidden or system files won't be selected. In fact in older Windows versions if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in a folder with hidden items **you'll get a warning** saying that there are hidden files in that folder

The warning has been removed in later versions of Windows but the behavior retains: You can't select something that you can't see

[image: XP select all warning]

Comment: This doesn't give substantial new information. Would better fit as a comment.

Comment: I don't agree. This gives a direct proof from Explorer instead of just a statement